# Why is it that when I do some substitution, I get $p=1$ for a photon?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics, photons

I know that this is wrong, but where did i make a mistake? I just use a few equations and substitutions and I get that the momentum of a photon is one. Here is my math:

$p=h/λ$

$p=hf/c$ (substituted using $λ=c/f$)

$c=hf/p$

$c=hc/λp$ (substituted $f=c/λ$)

$1=h/λp$ (divided by $c$)

$1=hλ/λph$ (substituted $p=h/λ$)

$1=p$

After that I substituted $p=h/λ$ and got that $λ=h$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: As a general method you can check the units of each line. The first time the units are wrong, then right there where the units are wrong you know that at least one mistake happened on that line (and maybe others on an earlier line, but at least one happened there, so find it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is right since $1=\frac{h}{\lambda{P}}$ . Then you say that you substitute for $P=\frac{h}{\lambda}$ then how you get next relation with $P$ included? You must replace $P$ by $\frac{h}{\lambda}$ and your equation become $1=\frac{h\lambda}{h\lambda}$ and this gives $1=1$ . So, this relation have no physical significance. But mathematicaly this equation is valid.

Answer (score 1):

In going from this step:

$\displaystyle 1=\frac{h}{λp}$ (divided by $c$)

to this step:

$\displaystyle 1=\frac{hλ}{λ\color{red}{p}h}$ (substituted $p=\frac hλ$)

shouldn't the $p$ on the RHS vanish after the substitution?